# Retained as pipeline resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In one of our Azure DevOps pipeline runs, I noticed "Retained as pipeline resource" retention lease. I have no idea how it happened, and could not find any documentation. Any help figuring this out is really appretiated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Pipelines that are consumed in other pipelines are not retained](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Pipelines-that-are-consumed-in-other-pip/1541630), this feature is being rolled out to customers.

Answer (score 0):

Yaml pipelines can specify another pipeline as a [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines).

```
resources:
  pipelines: [ pipeline ]  
  builds: [ build ]
  repositories: [ repository ]
  containers: [ container ]
  packages: [ package ]
  webhooks: [ webhook ]
```

This retention will ensure that the consumed pipeline run is retained for as long as the consumer pipeline is retained.

[image]

Besides, there is no documentation mentioned this feature as you said. Please report to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) for improvements.

Comment: I know about resources. But not all pipelines with resources result in consumed pipeline being retained with "Retained as pipeline resource". What I am trying to figure out is which setting controls it.

Comment: Sorry that I tried to search the details about this feature but no result. Could you please report to DC? Engineers there can do further investigation.

Comment: Looks like it has already been reported, see [Pipelines that are consumed in other pipelines are not retained](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Pipelines-that-are-consumed-in-other-pip/1541630).